# Django; empty model for Foreign Key attachment

Tags: python, sql, django, web

I'm building a CMS for a frequently asked questions page... I want "Frequently Asked Questions" to show up in the main admin menu and when clicked just reveal a big list of editable question/answer pairs. So there only needs to be one instance of the FAQ model and it doesn't need to have any information on its own... How would I do this?

```
class FAQ(models.Model):


class QandA(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey(FAQ)
    question = models.CharField()
    answer = models.CharField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

This returns the error that an indent is expected after `class FAQ(models.Model):` what do I need to add to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Syntactic answer:
You need at least a `pass` to satisfy Python's desire for an indented statement.
Semantic answer:
I'm not sure I understand 100% why you want that class in the first place, it sounds like a hack for the admin screen but maybe you could describe that more specifically.

Comment: Well, at first I was thinking I could put the fields `question` and `answer` in the main FAQ model, but then a separate instance of FAQ would have to be made for every question... I think. I want Foreign Key functionality where instead of one question at a time I can just have a big list of textfields on one page in the admin. I feel like I'm lacking some crucial understanding of the way Models work.

Comment: Don't worry doesn't look so bad I was just wondering if you only ever have one FAQ, what would you lose if you just removed `FAQ` and the corresponding `reference` field in `QandA`? A model represents a database table, so if you create the model only for UI reasons, there might be an easier way.

Comment: Using `pass` creates an ugly situation where I have to add an instance anyways and it gets automatically created as `FAQ Object`. I'm just going to add a field to FAQ for now. This will also allow me to split the questions into sections if desired. Thanks for giving me something to think about anyways.